# Cypress web automation - Cannot open Test Runner

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to open the Test Runner in cypress first time using the command node_modules.bin\cypress open
But I'm getting the following error.

Cypress verification timed out
Command failed "path"\cypress.exe\smoke test ping=948

I had tried all other open commands as well.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Not sure if its a typo, you might be missing a \  in the path: `node_modules\.bin\cypress open`

Comment: It was a typo. Error message as below.
PS C:\Users\Cypress Automation> node_modules\.bin\cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 4.7.0
Verifying Cypress can run :\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.7.0\Cypress
Cypress Version: 4.7.0 Cypress verification timed out.
This command failed with the following output: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.7.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=110Command failed:C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.7.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=110Platform: win32 (10.0.18362)
Cypress Version: 4.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was long ago, but I just had this problem, and in case anyone does in the future, I want to tell you how I solved it. In my case I had just installed Cypress in a project, and after running `npm install` the problem has been solved.